# gcloud app deploy not working - uses pip10 instead of pip19

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pip

I am trying to deploy a Flask app on Aoogle Cloud Platform using their App Engine functionality. The project builds fine but when it comes to installing the requirements using `requirements.txt` file, it just doesn't seem to work. Up to a point it installs the packages but after that it says `pip10` is used instead of `pip19` in installing the packages.

To overcome this, I forcefully added a `pip==19.0` dependency in the `requirements.txt` file.

Next, I created a virtual environment and locally upgraded pip and then tried to `gcloud app deploy` but to no effect.

I came across this [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/69Mds5n21k8) which also wasn't particularly helpful in resolving my question.

I have attached a screenshot below. Please let me know if anyone can fix it in earnest.
Thanking you'll for reading and in anticipation of a solution.

[image]

`requirements.txt`:

```
pip==20.1
numpy==1.18.3
attrs==19.3.0
backcall==0.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.0
bleach==3.1.4
blis==0.4.1
Bottleneck==1.3.2
catalogue==1.0.0
certifi==2020.4.5.1
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cycler==0.10.0
cymem==2.0.3
dataclasses==0.5
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
entrypoints==0.3
fastai==1.0.60
fastprogress==0.2.3
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Dropzone==1.5.4
Flask-Uploads==0.2.1
Frozen-Flask==0.15
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
importlib-metadata==1.6.0
ipykernel==5.2.1
ipython==7.13.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.17.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib==0.14.1
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter-client==6.1.3
jupyter-console==6.1.0
jupyter-core==4.6.3
kiwisolver==1.2.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.2.1
mistune==0.8.4
murmurhash==1.0.2
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==5.0.6
notebook==6.0.3
numexpr==2.7.1
nvidia-ml-py3==7.352.0
olefile==0.46
opencv-python==4.2.0.34
packaging==20.3
pandas==1.0.3
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.7.0
patsy==0.5.1
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==7.1.2
plac==1.1.3
preshed==3.0.2
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.5
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.6.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
PyQt5==5.12.3
PyQt5-sip==4.19.18
PyQtWebEngine==5.12.1
pyrsistent==0.16.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==19.0.0
qtconsole==4.7.3
QtPy==1.9.0
requests==2.23.0
scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.10.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.0
spacy==2.2.4
srsly==1.0.2
statsmodels==0.11.1
terminado==0.8.3
testpath==0.4.4
thinc==7.4.0
torch==1.0.1.post2
torchvision==0.2.2
tornado==6.0.4
tqdm==4.45.0
traitlets==4.3.3
urllib3==1.25.9
wasabi==0.6.0
wcwidth==0.1.9
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
xgboost==0.82
zipp==3.1.0
```

Comment: Please include your `requirements.txt` file. Also, for future reference, please don't include screenshots of text, please copy/paste the text into the question instead.

Comment: Thanks Destin. I am a novice and looking forward to learn more. I will keep this suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in those log messages:

> `Double requirement given: numpy==1.14.5 from ...`

Looking at your `requirements.txt` file, it looks like the output of `pip freeze`. There's a number of dependencies in there that you are probably not using in your application.

Your `requirements.txt` file should at a minimum only include dependencies that your application is actually `import`-ing.

Comment: No Dustin, It is not. Here's a link to the [requirements.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mR7cWdWSMnW4a2VQZhjzLbuKljUuEMIW/view?usp=sharing) file that I've used for your reference. 

I checked that once before...